# xml for accessing the repeater control row values in infopath form 

Tags: web-services, validation, list, infopath

I have  the web service, which has method  State() that returning the List. where i want to design the infopath form that having the repeating table. in repeating table one of column should have the drop down list.

I want to populate this List in the drop down list (states). Each selected instance in the dropdown must be unique means when i would select state A for row 1 then in other row there must be validation that should not select the state A again.

in short avoid the duplicate selection.

Comment: I am able to get records in the dropd down yet. but when i get selects the state in any row then that selected value sets to each drop down control in all rows..What have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include a section with a validation message under each dropdown. Select the section Properties > Display > Conditional formatting.

Set the condition as dropdown2_field is equal to dropdown1_field.
(Need to add similar multiple conditions for 3rd,4th successive dropdown boxes.)

and select Hide this control check box.

If the user selects the same state in dropdown2 the validation message is shown.

Comment: Hi shankar thanks for reply. But I would like to read my question once again. I have single dropdown control in my repeating table. so i wanted to selected item in drop down of row 1 should not be repeat in the other rows. what should be the formula for the same.

Comment: @Liladhar:Sorry! Then you probably have to use a validation event for your dropdown. Create the xpath navigator and compare the current repeater row value with its previous siblings, if they match display the error.

Comment: Ya i tried this sir, not(. = xdXDocument:get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:items/my:item/my:product) but unfortunately it is not working for me. i checked that "Preciding-sibling" is not working. What i have to do?

Comment: hello, would somebody help me here please

Comment: Or can we assign somehow composite key on repeating table in infopath to avoid the duplicate record insertion ?

Comment: You can post another question under xml for accessing the repeater control row values...May be someone will help.